# How to get a Substring from list of file names

Tags: batch-file

I want to develop the following logic

1. Read all files in a directory
2. Extract the first part of the filename – this will be the partner name
3. Extract anything after the first underscore- this will be filename
4. Eg: ZZTEST_123_abc_doc.txt  ZZTEST is partner. 123_abc_doc.txt is the filename.

Below is the code I developed

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Set Test_Dir=C:\Axway\projects\Cardinal\dosscript\test
cd %Test_Dir%

for /r %%a in (*.*) do (

     Set "fname1=%%~nxa"
     echo Filename is :!fname1!

    for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%i in ("!fname1!") do (
    Set "partner=%%i"
    echo Partner is :!partner!
    Set "str_tmp=!partner!_"
    echo !str_tmp!


    call :strlength length !str_tmp!
    echo !length!

    set fname=!fname1:~%length%!
    echo !fname1:~%length%!

    )

)
goto :eof

:strlength
setlocal enableextensions
set "#=%~2"
set length=0
:stringLengthLoop
if defined # (set "#=%#:~1%"&set /A length+=1&goto stringLengthLoop)
endlocal && set "%~1=%length%"
GOTO :EOF
```

But the result is

```
ID_ZZRoutingID_filename.txt
Filename is :ZZRoutingID_ZZRoutingID_filename1.txt
Partner is :ZZRoutingID
12
Result: ID_ZZRoutingID_filename1.txt
```

The result should be ZZRoutingID_filename1.txt but i am getting
ID_ZZRoutingID_filename1.txt.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the length calculation is not clear to me, but I would suggest adding an asterisk following the `1` in your `for /f "tokens=1 delims=_"`. You would then get the "filename" you were looking for through `%%j`.

I tested it like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set source=D:\Program Files\Somewhere
cd %source%

for /r %%i in (*.*) do (
  for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%j in ( "%%~nxi" ) do (
    echo partner: %%j
    echo name: %%k
  )
)

endlocal
```

If you do not need to recurse through sub-directories:

```
@echo off
set source=D:\Program Files\Somewhere

for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%i in ( 'dir "%source%" /b /a-d' ) do (
    echo partner: %%i
    echo filename: %%j
)
```

`dir /b /a-d` retrieves the list of a directory's content except its sub-directories:

```
D:\Program Files\Somewhere>dir /b /a-d
ZZTEST_123_456.txt
ABCDEF_890_FFF.doc
FOOBAR_567_@@@.zzz
```

Comment: Note that iterating over `dir`'s output will mangle certain file names in the default settings which you then cannot use within the loop. The normal looping mechanism over files is not affected by this and should therefore be preferred.

Comment: Actually there *can* be a point in splitting the names the OP's way. If the partner part is followed by two or more underscores, your solution and OP's would return different file name parts.

Comment: @Joey: Sorry for the late comment. What do you mean by "in the default settings" ? `DIR` switches already set in the `DIRCMD` environment variable, as stated in `DIR`'s command-line help ?
@Andriy: You are right, I assumed underscores could not be part of the "filename".

Comment: »Default settings« in this case means Raster fonts for the console window. Those will cause all output to be converted into the OEM codepage before acting on it with `for /f`. This will destroy Unicode file names with characters outside the OEM codepage. So usually you want to use just `for` unless you need filtering or sorting that cannot be accomplished in the normal loop.